# How to hide elements in dialog box?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, javascript, css, modal-dialog, style

In SP-2013 on prem, I am trying to hide all elements except the one element where one can browse for pictures, like shown in this picture where I want to hide everything inside the red square.

[image]

I wish to hide the elements with css, but it is not working. This is what I wrote in my css, and it is not working for me. Please advice.

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl13_tablerow1, #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl13_tablerow2,
#ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl13_tablerow3, #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl13_tablerow5, 
#ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl02_tablerow1, #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl02_tablerow2, 
#ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl02_tablerow3, #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl02_tablerow5,
#ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl14_tablerow1, #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl14_tablerow2, 
#ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl14_tablerow3, #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl14_tablerow5
{
display:none;
}

table.ms-authoringcontrols:first-child tr:nth-of-type(n+5){
display:none;
}
```

Comment: You need to try IE DOM (developer tools - F12) to identify proper IDs or classes for your controls & hide them.

Comment: These ID's are found by using developer tools.

Comment: are you able to hide controls by DOM?

Comment: If i write display:none on .element style in developer tools, yes. But not when it is applied in the css (the css code that can be seen in the opening post)

Answer (score 1):

Please try below CSS code.

```
.ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl13_tablerow1, .ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl13_tablerow2,
.ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl13_tablerow3, .ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl13_tablerow5, 
.ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl02_tablerow1, .ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl02_tablerow2, 
.ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl02_tablerow3, .ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl02_tablerow5,
.ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl14_tablerow1, .ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl14_tablerow2, 
.ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl14_tablerow3, .ms-dialog #ctl00_PlaceHolderDialogBodySection_PlaceHolderDialogBodyMainSection_ctl14_tablerow5
{
display:none;
}

.ms-dialog table.ms-authoringcontrols:first-child tr:nth-of-type(n+5){
display:none;
}
```

I have added `.ms-dialog` in your CSS which will find the IDs in dialog box.

Comment: Hi Hardik, and thanks for your reply. I have tried that also, but to no success. Have you tried it in your environment, and did it work for you  ?

Comment: Have you inserted that code in your parent page?

Comment: Please check this article...http://blog.sharepointexperience.com/2011/09/hide-page-elements-sharepoint-dialog-box/

Comment: Yes. I inserted it inside the css that is referenced to in the master page. I set it directly in the page layout, and also I tried to paste the css by using developer tools. It didn't work for me. Does the css work for you?

Comment: Yes i had tried it for my one of the display form of list.. Can you please try **display:none !important;**? it will overwrite the other css for display.

Comment: That I have tried also, without having any more success :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/40292/discussion-between-hardik-and-ilyas).